# depth_image_proc: How do we use it...exactly?

Tags: ros, depth-registered, asus-xtion-pro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Folks,

I can't get depth_image_proc to work. image_proc works, not problem, but the depth one is driving me crazy. I am already publishing a camera/depth_registered/image_raw topic (16bit mm), but I need the 32float version.

This how I tried to initialize depth_image_proc:

[image: image description]

I don't know what the "standalone_nodelet" part does, not the "--no-bond" part. I just saw other people's code on github and tried to use it. I even changed the standalone_nodelet parameter for my "camera/manager" nodelet, and nothing.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243802/depth_image_proc:-how-do-we-use-it...exactly?/) by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 803 on 2016-09-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I get it now. I had to use my camera's nodelete manager, and then add the topic I want to transform and then the name I want the topic to have after the transformation is done, like so:

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) with karma: 803 on 2016-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1